# Testng how to pass parameter to the listener

Tags: testng, listener

I would like to know a way to pass a parameter inside a listener eater from my suite.xml or by the code itself

I need this in parallel test to know exactly on which device I'm running a test in order to make some reports

this is an example of what I have / wish to achieve

the suite file

```
<suite name="SearchButton" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
    <test name="SamsungS6">
        <parameter name="deviceUDID"  value="04157df40862d02f"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="MyTestScenario"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

or

```
@Test
public void researchText (){
    String DeviceUDID = "1234";
}
```

I want to be able to find device UDID in my listener

```
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("My deviceUDID ");
}
```

I tried to find it with

```
System.getProperty("deviceUDID") // or
result.getAttribute() // or
result.getParameters()
```

without success

Any idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I did finally found a way to do it.
It can maybe be considered as a work around but it does the job.

In the ITestListener listener I've seen that we have a `onStart` method that allows me to access the parameter from the .xml file

```
    deviceUDID = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("deviceUDID");
```

And now that I have it inside the listener I just had to save it in variable and access it in the `onTestSkipped` method

Comment: Does this work for multiple threads ? Seems a good walkaround.

Answer (score 0):

`get*` methods cannot work if you don't use a `set*` somewhere else.

I see 2 options:

1. From the test by setting data in the `ITestContext` ([`ITestResult#getTestContext()`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestResult.html#getTestContext--)) which is injectable. See [the related documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection).
2. From the listener with an annotation metadata on the test method (ie: `@UDID("1234")`). But it may be more difficult to use in the test itself if you want avoid duplication.

---

According your example:

```
@Test
public void researchText(ITestContext context){
    String DeviceUDID = "1234";
    context.setAttribute("UDID", DeviceUDID)
}

public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("My deviceUDID " + result.getTestContext().getAttribute("UDID"));
}
```

or

```
<suite name="SearchButton" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
    <test name="SamsungS6">
        <parameter name="deviceUDID"  value="04157df40862d02f"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="MyTestScenario"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

@Parameters({ "deviceUDID" })
@Test
public void researchText (String DeviceUDID, ITestContext context){
    context.setAttribute("UDID", DeviceUDID)
}

public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("My deviceUDID " + result.getTestContext().getAttribute("UDID"));
}
```