# Read XML parameters values in Testlistener

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I am running TestNG via TestNG.xml, Is there any way I can read parameters from TestNG.xml to Itestlisteners. I wan to read  browsername value and URL value from below XML to my Testlistener.

TestNG.xml:-

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="TestListener"></listener>
```

```
<classes>
<class name="Login">

    <methods>
                <include name="OpenBrowser"></include>
                <parameter name="browsername" value="chrome"></parameter>
                <include name="EnterURL"></include>
                <parameter name="URL" value="https://www.ebay.com/"></parameter>

    </methods>
</class>
</classes>
```

Comment: You can find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077068/3161591

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in Test class level by using annotation @Parameters

```
@Parameters({"browsername", "URL"})
@Test(priority = 1)
public void test1(String browsername, String URL){
  System.out.println("param ::" +browsername);
  System.out.println("URL :: " +URL );
}
```

If you dont want to pull it to class level, parameterize the properties and pass the properties at the time of execution.

Comment: Thanks .. But I want to access these parameters in my TestLlisterner.